# How can I migrate multiple ec2 instances and RDS to another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a migration project where I am tasked with migrating multiple ec2 instances and RDS database to another region?

I have tried creating a snapshot and copying it to the new region and create an AMI from that snapshot, but I have to do this one by one and I was wondering if I there is a way, I will be able to accomplish this task at once.

Comment: This is really a question better asked on https://serverfault.com/ as it's much more of a system administrator question.  But ultimately what you want to do is a challenge.  Hopefully you have repeatable code to create the new environment the same way as the existing one.  I would likely start with the RDS instances if possible.  Allow access from your current EC2's to the RDS instances in the new region.  Get that stable.  Then move one EC2 at a time.  Good luck - this is a good amount of work.

Comment: Using EC2 AMIs and RDS Snapshots is the correct method. There is no 'out of the box' method for migrating these. If the EC2 instances have no local state information stored, then they can be migrated ahead of time with no need to 'sync-up' at the end. Then, you'll need an outage period for the database Snapshot + Copy + Restore.

Comment: These might help. 1. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/multi-region-migration-using-aws-application-migration-service/ 2. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-amazon-aurora-and-amazon-rds-to-a-new-aws-region/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. After doing some research I learned that there is no migrate all the resources at once. I have a couple of options to try. I can try cloudendure, application migration services, database migration service or just import all the resources into terraform and then take it from there. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: Only keep in mind that importing all resources to the terraform and "take it from there" will allow you only recreate VM's and DB's with needed paramerers/configurations, terraform will not be responsible to your data.

Comment: That is very true, do you know if Former2 also only recreates the resources but does not recreate the data?